# Hot observable with filters RX Java

Tags: java, android, filter, rx-java

I am trying to create a hot observable with **filtering** in register method as list of events that are implementing a base interface as below:

```
public void register(Observer<AppEvent> observer, List<AppEvent> filter) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Registering observer");
        subject.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .filter(o -> {
                    return filter.stream().anyMatch(it -> (o instanceof it));
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(observer);
    }

    public interface AppEvent extends Serializable {
    }

    public static class ItemDetails implements AppEvent {
        public String info;

        public ItemDetails(String malwareInfo) {
            info = malwareInfo;
        }
    }

    public static class InitApi implements AppEvent {
        public Boolean isSuccess;

        public InitApi(boolean isSuccess) {
            this.isSuccess = isSuccess;
        }
    }
```

What I am trying to do is to have a **filter** based on type of event class, in our case ItemDetails or InitApi.
Logically the code is correct:

```
 .filter(o -> {
                    return filter.stream().anyMatch(it -> (o instanceof it));
                })
```

but the compiler says `unknown class it`.

How can I do filtering over a list of AppEvent?

Comment: The argument to `instanceof` needs to be the name of a type, i.e. class or interface. `it` is not the name of a class or interface. Hence the compiler error that _`it` is not a class_

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you're seeing the compiler error because the `instanceof` operator requires the right-hand-side argument to be either a class or an interface.

If you're trying to create an "allowed" list of events to pass on to the `Observer`, you could do something like this:

```
public void register(Observer<AppEvent> observer, List<AppEvent> filter) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Registering observer");

    // Collect the names of events to pass on to the observer
    final List<String> allowedEventNames = filter.stream()
        .map(it -> it.getClass().getName())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    subject.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            // Filter based on names
            .filter(event -> allowedEventNames.contains(event.getClass().getName()))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(observer);
}
```